# Android - spinner - setOnItemSelectedListener how to get selected object from arrayList?

Tags: android

I use spinner with adapter which gets values from arrayList

```
Spinner sourcesSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ad1_filter_source_spinner);
    List<SO_Item> sources = helper.getItems();

    ArrayAdapter<SO_Item> sourcesadapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<SO_Item>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, sources);
    sourcesadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    sourcesSpinner.setAdapter(sourcesadapter);
```

How to get object from selected value from listener?

```
sourcesSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: usually, the position should be the same, so try to get `sources.get(position)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sourcesSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               SO_Item selectedItem = sources.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

or

```
SO_Item selectedItem = sources.get(sourcesSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
```

Comment: Thanks, short and simple solution